# Apache Spark: cache and partitions

Tags: caching, collections, apache-spark, rdd

Here's situation: I have a constantly growing collection of data, which I want to process using RDD across the Hadoop cluster.

Here is the short example:

```
val elementA = (1, Seq(2, 3))
val elementB = (2, Seq(1, 3))
val elementC = (3, Seq(1, 2))

val testRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(elementA, elementB, elementC)).
    map(x => (x._1, x._2)).setName("testRDD").cache()

val elementD = (4, Seq(1, 3))
val elementD1 = (1, Seq(4))
val elementD2 = (3, Seq(4))

val testAdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(elementD, elementD1, elementD2)).
    map(x => (x._1, x._2)).setName("testAdd")

val testResult = testRDD.cogroup(testAdd).mapValues(x => (x._1 ++ x._2).flatten)
```

The result will be like this (order of elements can vary):

```
(1, List(2, 3, 4))
(2, List(1, 3))
(3, List(1, 2, 4))
(4, List(1, 3))
```

Here's my goals:

1. I want to `.cache()` my RDD in cluster memory.
2. I want to have the ability to add new elements to the existing RDD.

Here's what I've figured out:

1. Each partition in RDD caches separately and entirely (for example, I had the collection with 100 elements and 4 partitions, I called `.cache().collect()` and `cache().first()` and got 4 cached partitions in first case and 1 in second case).
2. The result of `testRDD.cogroup(testAdd)` is new RDD, that could be cached again, and if we'll try to use `var testRDD` and call `testRDD = testRDD.cogroup(testAdd)`, we'll lose the link to the cached data.
3. I know, that RDD is most suiltable for batch applications, and I have this here: the `Seq()` for each new element will be computed from the properties of another elements.

> Is there any way to modify current RDD without removing all of it's elements from cache?

I though about making a kind of temporary storage and merging temporary storage with current storage after reaching some limit on temporary storage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDDs are immutable so you can't add new elements to them.  You can however create a new RDD by unioning your original RDD with the new elements, similarly to what you did with your testResult RDD.

If you want to use the same variable for the new RDD with the updates you could use a var rather that a val for that RDD.  e.g.

`var testRDD = sc.parallelize(...)
val testAdd = sc.parallelize(...)
testRDD = testRDD.union(testAdd)
testRDD.cache()`

This will create a lineage joining the two original RDDs.  This could cause issues if you call union on testRDD too many times.  To fix that you can call checkpoint on testRDD after it has been union-ed so many times, say every 10 updates.  You could also consider calling repartion on testRDD when checkpointing.

All elements added to testRDD should stay in the cache using this technique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but here's another question - there are will be definitely some changes in already cached elements (see my example in question), how using `var` hepls me here? Can I just call `testRDD.cache()` on `var testRDD` and it will automatically cache my updates after actions? Quite hard to believe in this magic...

Comment: I think you will need to call `testRDD.cache()` each time you add (union) more elements, which in effect creates a new RDD.

Comment: No, you don't need to call `.cache()` again, it will create new `MapPartitionRDD` (_in my case_). But seems like you can call `.cache()` once for your `var testRDD`.

Comment: OK, good to know.  Like I said in my answer watch our for lineage issues and consider calling `testRDD.checkpoint()` and `testRDD.repartition(x)` every so many iterations.

Comment: And another thing - new RDD created by `testRDD = testRDD.union(_)` will make previous cached RDD unavailable for `.unpersist()` calls (we'll lose the link to it, so we need to call `.unpersist()` before reassinging `var` variable), so I think that I can't save variables in cache after updating RDD... Unfortunately :(

Comment: Yes, that is true.  Another way of doing this is keeping a reference to the old RDD and calling unpersist after the union, so that the RDD is in the cache when it is being unioned.  e.g. `val oldTestRDD = testRDD`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82463/discussion-between-suppierk-and-patrick-mcgloin).